# WSO2 Integrator hosted REST API calling another REST API for POST calls not working

Tags: post, wso2, call

I have created a REST API service which is calling another REST API through a POST request. I am using the call , send mediators to call the third party service hosted on same machine.When I try to call the WSO2 REST API the service is unable to call the third party service. The service drops message with a timeout or see an Exceeption that cannot send the call through sendPostURL.

I have tried using both send and call mediators (blocking, non blocking ) but the request never completes.

The authentication on third party API is Basic ( username/password).
Not sure what I am doing incorrect.

Following is the API request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/xyz" name="XYZPostAPI" statistics="enable" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Input"/>
            <Header> variables
            <call blocking="true">
                <endpoint key="XYZPost"/>
            </call>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log description="Response">
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="JSON-Payload"/>
            </log>
            <respond description="batchId"/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log description="FaultDetails">
                <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occurred"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="message"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="code"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_DETAIL" name="detail"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_EXCEPTION" name="exception"/>
            </log>
            <respond description="fault"/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Error seen:
a.
[2020-04-06 10:05:00,712]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /nuxeopost, MessageID: urn:uuid:e445d272-b9eb-4e89-84f1-428c622213b8, Direction: request
[2020-04-06 10:05:00,713]  INFO {API_LOGGER.NuxeoPostAPI} - To: /nuxeopost, MessageID: urn:uuid:e445d272-b9eb-4e89-84f1-428c622213b8, Direction: request
[2020-04-06 10:05:00,714]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Sending message through endpoint : NuxeoPost resolving to address = http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload
[2020-04-06 10:05:00,714]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - SOAPAction: null
[2020-04-06 10:05:00,715]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - WSA-Action: null
[2020-04-06 10:05:03,735]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} - Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: 
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:492)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:384)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:569)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:408)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:96)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:56)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:165)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:440)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:113)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:325)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:412)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2020-04-06 10:05:03,762]  WARN {API_LOGGER.NuxeoPostAPI} - ERROR_CODE : 401 ERROR_MESSAGE : Transport error: 401 Error: 
[2020-04-06 10:05:03,763]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Endpoint : NuxeoPost with address http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2020-04-06 10:05:03,764]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Suspending endpoint : NuxeoPost with address http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Apr 06 10:05:33 IST 2020
[2020-04-06 10:05:03,764]  INFO {API_LOGGER.NuxeoPostAPI} - FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
[2020-04-06 10:05:03,765]  WARN {API_LOGGER.NuxeoPostAPI} - Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator

b.
2020-04-06 09:48:02,801]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9164
[2020-04-06 09:49:04,842]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /nuxeopost, MessageID: urn:uuid:01e07a5c-93b7-47b8-a8f6-b04f6da03649, Direction: request
[2020-04-06 09:49:04,842]  INFO {API_LOGGER.NuxeoPostAPI} - To: /nuxeopost, MessageID: urn:uuid:01e07a5c-93b7-47b8-a8f6-b04f6da03649, Direction: request
[2020-04-06 09:49:04,844]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Sending message through endpoint : NuxeoPostSample resolving to address = http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload
[2020-04-06 09:49:04,844]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - SOAPAction: null
[2020-04-06 09:49:04,844]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - WSA-Action: null
[2020-04-06 09:49:04,853]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} - This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2020-04-06 09:51:19,854]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} - Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:d6945cd0-6e98-4dfb-a837-5d764cd3cabd; dropping message after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT of : 120 seconds for Endpoint [NuxeoPostSample], URI : http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload, Received through API : NuxeoPostAPI
[2020-04-06 09:52:04,850]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2020-04-06 09:52:04,851]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-3 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:56896